# How to clear the pixel of a spriterenderer ata given world position

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a sprite renderer scaled to fill screen and i need to clear the pixel at a given world position.

I have tried converting world position to screenpoint but it is displaced,the farther the coord the difference is bigger between the world position and the convertion, i suppose i have to use some math algorithm but i am not good at it.

Comment: How are the world and the image correlated?

Comment: I dont know what you mean exaclty.the image is in the center of the screen-world origin and it is scaled its y and x to fill screen.

Comment: How does the world relate to the image?  Please include enough detail for others to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I dont have an issue.i just need the algorithm to convert  the world position to hte correct pixel in that rendered sprite texture.the image is 1230x760 i had to scale its gameobject using an algorithm to fill the screen.the method i tried is not the right one because i am using screen point and using its value to access texture coord which is different.so  what i need is to find the correct math formula to make the conversion.i am not a math guy i dont know how to explain this.,the image is in the center of the world and is stretched to fill screen.I hope i have made myself clear this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need take the world position, do some math to get it within the bounds of the SpriteRenderer, and then do some more math to find its position within the texture.

This code below will clear a pixel from the texture of a Sprite when you click on it, if you attach this script to a GameObject with a SpriteRenderer. It should contain what you are looking for.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // example: get world position from click
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0.0f));

        SpriteRenderer renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        // get pixel position in texture
        Vector2Int pixelPosition = GetPixelPositionInTexture(renderer, worldPos);

        // do what we want with that pixel to the texture
        // in this case, clear the pixel
        Texture2D tex = renderer.sprite.texture;
        tex.SetPixel(pixelPosition.x, pixelPosition.y, new Color());
        tex.Apply();
    }

    private Vector2Int GetPixelPositionInTexture(SpriteRenderer renderer, Vector3 worldPosition)
    {
        // bounds of the sprite renderer in the world
        Bounds bounds = renderer.bounds;
        // rect of the sprite within the texture
        Rect rect = renderer.sprite.rect;

        // get local position
        Vector2 localPos = worldPosition - bounds.min;

        // normalize the positon within the sprite
        Vector2 normalPos = new Vector2(localPos.x / bounds.size.x, localPos.y / bounds.size.y);

        // get the pixel positon within the sprite
        Vector2Int spritePixelPos = Vector2Int.FloorToInt(new Vector2(normalPos.x * rect.width, normalPos.y * rect.height));

        // get the pixel position within the texture
        Vector2Int texPixelPos = new Vector2Int(Mathf.FloorToInt(rect.x + spritePixelPos.x), Mathf.FloorToInt(rect.y + spritePixelPos.y));

        return texPixelPos;
    }
}
```

This code will not work if the camera or SpriteRenderer has been rotated or flipped. It will work with scaled GameObjects, and Sprites set to the Multiple sprite mode.

Comment: Thanks ill try it asap.Also if you have any link to some courses related to math stuff related to video games or unity share it if you can.

Comment: Yeah, the script works perfect.i hope some day solve this problems by myself.Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lesnier You are most welcome. Sadly I do not have any particular videos or resources for what I did. I would recommend using a notebook and pen, and some trial and error, which usually does the trick for me when I have to do something more math heavy like this.